# jQuery hide() hides what it shouldn't

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I've got problem... jQuery should only hide divs under each h2, but it hides those h2 aswell... What should I do?

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Yolo</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="faq">
            <h2>Opcja 1</h2>
            <div class="answer">
                <p>Paragraph under option 1!</p>
            </div>
            <h2>Opcja 2</h2>
            <div class="answer">
                <p>Paragraph under option 2!</p>
            </div>
            <h2>Opcja 3</h2>
            <div class="answer">
                <p>Paragraph under option 3!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/szkrypt.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And there is jQuery. I did this via course in book, there it worked, maybe there was something with css classes there... Or maybe it was that, it was done under older version of jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.answer').hide();
 $('.faq h2').toggle(
        function() {
           $(this).next('.answer').slideDown();
        },
        function() {
           $(this).next('.answer').fadeOut();
      }
    );
});
```

Comment: you are loading jquery twice there

Comment: You are hiding all .answers. Give one an ID or use .eq() http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The toggle function you're trying to use is **deprecated and removed** !

The only `toggle()` function that is left in jQuery, is the one that toggles visibility, and that's why it's hiding everything.

```
$('.faq h2').toggle();
```

... hides every visible `h2` element, and shows every hidden `h2` element

You'll have to create your own toggle

```
$('.answer').hide();
$('.faq h2').on('click', function() {
    var flag = $(this).data('flag');

    if ( !flag ) {
       $(this).next('.answer').slideDown();
    } else {
      $(this).next('.answer').fadeOut();
    }

    $(this).data('flag', !flag);
});
```

Also, remove the script tag that is loading jQuery in the head, once is enough !